# How do I get my server off the ivmSIP blacklist?

Tags: email, email-bounces, blacklist, blacklist-prevention

On March 22nd I was notified by MX Toolbox that my server ip was blacklisted by ivmSIP and Hostkarma Black. I was aware of an attack some of our clients sites had suffered towards the end of January but we immediately took those sites offline and advanced security. So, I was surprised to find we were blacklisted.

I emailed both of the Blacklist companies explaining what had happened and what action we took. Hostkarma removed us immediately but ivmSIP has totally ignored all 7 emails I have sent to them over the past 8 days.

I have the impression that I need to accept their offer to sign up and pay a monthly fee to get removed. Is that the answer to resolve?

My question is, can anybody tell me what I can do to get these guys to de-list my ip? Obviously sending detailed emails explaining everything is of no use and I have no idea if they have even been read.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you
Bryan

Comment: Did you try the "delist requests" button at the top of every page? https://www.invaluement.com/removal/

Comment: Two things: As @ceejayoz suggest, try the official delist request on their page. The other option you gave doesn't make sense from a legal standpoint, this would be ransom. Depending on where your company is located and how much the cost are, it might make more sense to have a lawyer send a nice letter to them.

Comment: I have tried the delist request 3 times. I am based in Australia and attempting to take legal action against an off shore company is difficult and expensive. It would be easier for me to get a new ip and update all my clients DNS records

Comment: UPDATE: I have just checked my ip on the MX blacklist and I am no longer listed. It appears that going public may have worked for me in this instance. Thank you for your comments.